# Remove text input underline border in React Native in dark mode

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput, darkmode

Underline border appears in React Native Textinput **when in dark** mode of the device, When switch to **light mode it's gone**

[TextInput when in light mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15IMZ.jpg) <---- screenshot

[TextInput when in dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSooX.jpg) <---- screenshot

**This is the react native style sheet code**

```
textInput: {
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
borderBottomWidth: 0,
paddingRight: 5,
paddingLeft: 15,
color: colors.light__0,
fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
},
```

**Here is the TextInput JSX code**

```
    <TextInput
    onChangeText={() => handleChange()}
    onBlur={handleBlur()}
    value={value}
    style={styles.textInput}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    autoCompleteType={autoCompleteType}
    secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
    keyboardType={keyboardType}
    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
    placeholderTextColor={colors.light__40}
    ></TextInput>
```

Comment: whats the color of underline ? and please provide some screen shot or code.

Comment: and whats the model of device ?

Comment: Android version 9, Model : RMX1811, Oppo realme

Comment: can you please share  textinput code?

Comment: Just added the code

Comment: Just tested the above code, works fine